# How would I import fonts from google fonts into javascript, so i can use it for my canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to import google fonts into javascript, so I can use the fonts to draw text on my canvas. The problem is that I am receiving errors.
Error 1:Failed to decode download fonts
Error 2:OTS parsing error

This is for a web page I'm developing, and I looked up the problems, but the solutions they suggested, I don't understand.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var pacifico_font = new FontFace('Pacifico', 'url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&display=swap)');
pacifico_font.load().then(function(loaded_face) {
    document.fonts.add(loaded_face);
    document.body.style.fontFamily = '"Pacifico", Pacifico';
}).catch(function(error) {
    alert("An error occured, please continue.");
});
document.fonts.ready.then(function(font_face_set) {
    var x = true;
    return x;
});
ctx.fillStyle=rgb(0,0,0);
if(x===true){
ctx.font="20px Pacifico";
ctx.fillText("Hello Cody(testing)",200,200);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the canvas to show text, but it alert me to that there was an error, and there is nothing.
In the console it says:
Failed to decode downloaded font: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&display=swap
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading a stylesheet not a font.

Here is the solution:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&display=swap">
    </head>
        <body>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
            <!--window.onload won't work without this because there is nothing waiting for the link to load-->
            <span id="loader" style="font-family: Pacifico;">I am used for loading</span>
    <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="rgb(0,0,0)";
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("loader").style.display="none"
      ctx.font="20px Pacifico";
      ctx.fillText("I am inside of canvas",200,200);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I wish to put the text inside the canvas.

Comment: It does put the text in the canvas, the span is just used to make sure the text isn't drawn before the font is loaded. I have added a snippet to show you.

Comment: wait, why must I use window.onload? Isn't there any other way to do this without window.onload? Because I have a extra bit of code i was planning to use in the script tag.

Comment: You have to use `window.onload` because otherwise it could draw the text before the font was loaded meaning it would just use the default font. You could use `document.getElementById("loader").onload` instead if you want.

Comment: How would I use it then?

Comment: What is the extra code and why can't you just add it to `window.onload?

Comment: Yes, i can add it the window.onload function, but I wish to be able to not have to use it all the time.

Comment: Using `window.onload` is the most efficient way to do it. I could add a different way to do it, but that would involve using more code. If you would like alternatives to `window.onload` consider asking another question.

Answer (score 2):

The font link you're using is actually a link to a stylesheet.

You can get the direct link to the font by visiting the stylesheet link.

It'll display the following CSS:

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Pacifico Regular'), local('Pacifico-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v16/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6K6MmBp0u-zK4.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Pacifico Regular'), local('Pacifico-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v16/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6D6MmBp0u-zK4.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Pacifico Regular'), local('Pacifico-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v16/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6I6MmBp0u-zK4.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Pacifico Regular'), local('Pacifico-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v16/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6J6MmBp0u-zK4.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Pacifico Regular'), local('Pacifico-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v16/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6H6MmBp0u-.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Just grab the link to whichever version of the font you'd like to use and add it in place of where you're currently adding the stylesheet.

Comment: I meant I want to use it for my canvas. The purpose of the link is to obtain the font so I can use it for my canvas.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, but hard to understand. The link for most characters is https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v16/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6H6MmBp0u-.woff2

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href =
  "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work with me:

```
let myFont = new FontFace("Pacifico",
                          "url(/assets/fonts/fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf)"
                        );

myFont.load().then((font) => {   
    document.fonts.add(font);
    console.log("Font loaded"); 

    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="rgb(0,0,0)";
    ctx.font="20px Pacifico";
    ctx.fillText("I am inside of canvas",200,200);
    ctx.stroke();
});
```